# good way to return all deeply object's nested keys with values in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, data-structures

I need to access and return all deeply nested key's in an object and return them based on a key.

For example I have

```
const chatSettings = {
  name: {
    questions: {
      question: 'What\'s your name?',
      fields: [
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'text',
          key: 'firstname',
          label: 'First name'
        },
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'text',
          key: 'lastname',
          label: 'Last name'
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  email: {
    questions: {
      question: 'Okay. {{username}}. Now type your email addess',
      fields: [
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'email',
          key: 'email',
          label: 'Email'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And I need something like, `getAllValuesForKey(chatSettings, 'key')`, which would return `['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']`

Any ideas how to do it in a performant way while as well taking into account that some of these objects might not even have this key?

Comment: You could write a function that traverses your object (maybe recursively) and picks keys. You can also use a library like, say, Lodash that has this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: *iterate key/value pairs of object, if the value is an object, call the function with this object, otherwise if the key matches the search criteria add it to the list of matches* - I guess that's a basic algorithm, but what if you search for a key whose value is an object rather than a primitive (e.g, what if you searched for `questions`), should that object be included in the list of matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create recursive function with `reduce` method and return array as a result.

```js
const data = {"name":{"questions":{"question":"What's your name?","fields":[{"field":"textinput","type":"text","key":"firstname","label":"First name"},{"field":"textinput","type":"text","key":"lastname","label":"Last name"}]}},"email":{"questions":{"question":"Okay. {{username}}. Now type your email addess","fields":[{"field":"textinput","type":"email","key":"email","label":"Email"}]}}}

function find_deep(data, key) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((r, e) => {
    if (typeof data[e] == 'object') r.push(...find_deep(data[e], key))
    if (key == e) r.push(data[e])
    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(find_deep(data, 'key'))
```

Comment: even tidier using `Object.entries`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function with a type check and reduce the object.

```js
function getValues(object, key) {
    return object && typeof object === 'object'
        ? Object
            .entries(object)
            .reduce((r, [k, v]) => r.concat(k === key ? v : getValues(v, key)), [])
        : [];
}

var chatSettings = { name: { questions: { question: 'What\'s your name?', fields: [{ field: 'textinput', type: 'text', key: 'firstname', label: 'First name' }, { field: 'textinput', type: 'text', key: 'lastname', label: 'Last name' },] } }, email: { questions: { question: 'Okay. {{username}}. Now type your email addess', fields: [{ field: 'textinput', type: 'email', key: 'email', label: 'Email' }] } } },
    values = getValues(chatSettings, 'key');

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const chatSettings = {
  name: {
    questions: {
      question: 'What\'s your name?',
      fields: [
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'text',
          key: 'firstname',
          label: 'First name'
        },
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'text',
          key: 'lastname',
          label: 'Last name'
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  email: {
    questions: {
      question: 'Okay. {{username}}. Now type your email addess',
      fields: [
        {
          field: 'textinput',
          type: 'email',
          key: 'email',
          label: 'Email'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

function getAllValuesByKey(obj, key) {
  let values = []
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(o => {
      let value = getAllValuesByKey(o, key)
      if(value && value.length > 0) {
        values = values.concat(value)
      }
    })
  } else if(typeof obj === 'object') {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      if(k == key) {
        values.push(obj[k])
      }
      if(Array.isArray(obj[k]) || typeof obj[k] == 'object') {
        let value = getAllValuesByKey(obj[k], key)
        if(value && value.length > 0) {
          values = values.concat(value)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  return values
}

console.log(getAllValuesByKey(chatSettings, 'key'))
```